# UIActivity ViewController Display Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

So I already have my Activity controller linked to a share button working fine. It populates the text and images whenever i point to a specific item, however Im using an Array of text and images and I want it to automatically populate the items on array when the user swipes to the next page. But it doesn't seem to be presenting itself correctly. Here is my code below:

```
{
    NSString *shareApp2 = @"Test Share Button";
    UIImage *shareImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"challenge@2x.png"];
    NSString *shareChallenge = @"Challenge";
    NSArray *shareDays2 = self.pageDays2;
    NSArray *shareText2 = self.pageTitles2;
    NSArray *itemsToShare2 = @[shareApp2, shareImage2, shareChallenge, shareDays2, shareText2,];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare2 applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The issue is on these two lines:

```
NSArray *shareDays2 = self.pageDays2;
NSArray *shareText2 = self.pageTitles2;
```

If I present it like this it will work fine but it will only populate the specific item on the array I point it to as an Integer:

```
NSArray *shareDays2 = self.pageDays2 [0];
NSArray *shareText2 = self.pageTitles2 [0];
```

Ive tried multiple ARC and Count or self presenting methods and have no luck, I know its something real simple I'm over looking. If you need source file or more detail please let me know, thanks

Comment: What's pageDays2 and pageTitles2 ? Can we have more code about them initialization ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code for sharing:**

```
NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";

NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codingexplorer.com/"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Reference:** http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/